# MySQL INSERT data does not get stored in proper db, only temporary?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having trouble with MySQL or Python and can't seem to isolate the problem. `INSERT`s only seem to last the run of the script and are not stored in the database.

I have this script:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="password", db="example")
dbcursor = db.cursor()

dbcursor.execute("select * from tablename")
temp = dbcursor.fetchall()
print 'before: '+str(temp)

dbcursor.execute('INSERT INTO tablename (data1, data2, data3) VALUES ("1", "a", "b")')

dbcursor.execute("select * from tablename")
temp = dbcursor.fetchall()
print 'after: '+str(temp)
```

The first time I run it I get the expected output:

```
>>> 
before: ()
after: ((1L, 'a', 'b'),)
```

The problem is that if I run it again, the `before` comes out empty when it should already have the entry in it and the after doesn't break (data 1 is primary key).

```
>>> 
before: ()
after: ((1L, 'a', 'b'),)
>>> 
before: ()
after: ((1L, 'a', 'b'),)
>>> 
before: ()
after: ((1L, 'a', 'b'),)
```

If I try running the insert command twice in the same script it will break ("Duplicate entry for PRIMARY KEY")

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not committing the transaction.

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                        user = "testuser",
                        passwd = "testpass",
                        db = "test")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(...)
conn.commit()
```

[Reference](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/pydbapi.html)

Comment: If it isn't in the DB, why does the second select return that value? Is this the difference between transactional and non-transactional DBs?

Comment: @joaoc The second select returns the value because the result of the INSERT is visible to your own session, but not visible for others until you commit it

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to call

db.commit()

Comment: After every dbcursor.execute or only once at the end?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are not committing the changes. it can be done by
    conn.commit()

read more on this [here](http://sahanlm.blogspot.com/2012/10/mysqldb-does-not-commit-then-read-this.html)