# Python don't register in MySQL server

Tags: python, mysql

there’s something wrong in my python script: when I try to put some data in my database and print it, it looks like it’s working, but when I rerun the code, or if I check the phpmyadmin, there’s no data saved in the db. Does anyone have some idea on how to solve this problem?

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode


def connect():
    """ Connect to MySQL database """
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='Temperature',
                                       user='Temperature',
                                       password='mypass')
        if conn.is_connected():
            print('Connected to MySQL database')
            cur = conn.cursor()

            query = "INSERT INTO Temp(temp, humi) " \
            "VALUES(315, 55)"
            try:
                cur.execute(query)
            except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError as e:
                print(e)

            query = "SELECT * FROM Temp"
            try:
                cur.execute(query)
                for reading in cur.fetchall():
                    print (str(reading[0])+"    "+str(reading[1]))
            except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError as e:
                print(e)

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    finally:
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

Comment: You forgot to commit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL INSERT data does not get stored in proper db, only temporary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387573/mysql-insert-data-does-not-get-stored-in-proper-db-only-temporary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`. That should solve the problem.